# For someone who loves mathematics - the more theoretical, the better - what type of engineering would you recommend?

Tags: meta-math

I'm thinking there must be a type of engineering where math is strongly involved. What type of engineering would you suggest?

Comment: Any field of engineering will involve a significant amount of mathematics. It's you that decides the amount of math that's involved, not your field. Your field can at best decide the *type* of mathematics involved.

Comment: On balance, electronic engineering would use a wider variety of mathematical techniques than other disciplines. Specializing towards communications on the broad sense (network traffic problems, information theory, silicon chip design and logic, filter design, control...) can get pretty cutting edge mathematically. How deep you go depends on what a particular department might specialize in as far as research goes.

Comment: Generally speaking, any form of engineering or physics will have a fairly heavy amount of mathematics in it.  Electrical engineering definitely has problems which involve you in mathematical techniques from other areas (transform theory for example) but fluid mechanics will involve you more in the approximation techniques side of thing.  It really depends on the kind of mathematics you want to do and the research that is available.

Answer (score 0):

Electrical engineering in my opinion .However if you are more intrested in pure mathematics loaded with some engineering background.I suggest you to go with Theoretical  Computer Science/Cryptology.It surely contains the beauty of pure mathematics with application in it.

Comment: This is not a complete answer. I know you do not have reputation points, but such remarks should be mentioned more as comments.